# PHP: XOR to 2 text strings: can't see the result

Tags: php, encryption, xor

I try to write simple `xor encryption` in `PHP 5`. But I can't see the result of `xor` operation. For example,

```
$s1="abcd";
$s2="efgh";
$res1 = $s1 ^ $s2;
$res2 = $res1 ^ $s2;
echo $res1, $res2;
```

displays `$res2`, but `$res1` isn't showed. I tried to do this encryption separately for each char in string, but I got same result. As I understood, in real situation, the key and the result must to be `HEX-strings`.

But I can't see `$res1` as `HEX-number` using `printf`. Maybe, I need to pack("H*",...) `s1` and `s2` `strings` before using `XOR`, but then I can't correctly unpack results (as text string and hex-number respectively).

Comment: PHP doesn't magically convert unprintable characters into hex. Use [bin2hex()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php).

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to do this conversion.